# Is it possible to manage geometry modularly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a code that I'm trying to handle the geometry of a button in a frame and entry in another frame. But it doesn't seem to work independently of the main window they're both children of.

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class NumPad(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.button = tk.Button(text=0)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')


class CalcFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame1 = CalcFrame(master=root)
    frame2 = NumPad(master=root)
    frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    root.mainloop()
```

In the above code if I replace:

```
self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

with:

```
self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

the widget in `frame2` overlaps the widget on `frame1`. How can I have an inner grid per widget basis? Right now it seems like there's only one top-level grid.

Comment: Well, it seems you got what you want if you do not do that change, so why to change?

Comment: You aren't giving the buttons a parent/master, so it defaults to the root window.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I think I've managed to solve this setting master parameter on the buttons, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bryan Oakley pointed out in the comments above, when you declare the `Button` widget on this line...

```
self.button = tk.Button(text=0)
```

You aren't assigning it a parent meaning that it just dumps itself into the `Tk()` window by default.

On a side note, you have variables which by their name suggest that they are `Frame` widgets (namely `frame1` and `frame2`) but actually appear to be references to classes which don't ever use `Frame` widgets.

`Frame` widgets are very powerful and can be used to easily separate sets of widgets in the same window. An example of using `Frames` can be found below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
frame2 = Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")

frame1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
frame2.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

label1 = Label(frame1, text="I'm inside a frame")
label2 = Label(frame2, text="I'm inside a different frame")

label1.pack()
label2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

This shows that you can have widgets using a different geometry manager to their parents:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame2 = Frame(root)

frame1.pack(side="left")
frame2.pack(side="right")

label1 = Label(frame1, text="I'm grid")
label2 = Label(frame1, text="I'm grid")
label3 = Label(frame2, text="I'm pack")
label4 = Label(frame2, text="I'm pack")

label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
label3.pack()
label4.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm still unable to grid frames that have widgets in them that have their geometry managed by .pack though, is this normal?

Comment: @Nae I've updated my answer to prove that you most certainly can have widgets with different geometry managers than their parents. What you can't do is have multiple geometry managers within the same parent.